# Old constructive question closed as not constructive

Tags: discussion

I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596999/color-picker-for-windows-forms-application) question from 2011 that was closed in 2013 as "not constuctive"

Could somebody explain why? In my opinion, this is a clear and valid question as it stands (though not perfect).

From the close text:

> We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise

I don't think this is needed in this question. It is clear and has good tags.

> this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion

I strongly disagree. It is rather a yes/no question (though it is clear that a plain "yes" or "no" is not the expected answer), not a broad or opinion-based one.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question.  Right now it reads like a shopping question, there are *lots* of color pickers around.  But then again, if ColorDialog is the correct answer then, ugh, we don't need more answers to that question.

Comment: The question is clear, but it is extremely *underspecified*. "Are there any ..." The answer is undoubtedly yes, lots of things exist.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on close text, often they are not exact matches to the particular situation, but a close second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's one of the reasons why the "not constructive" close reason was done away with. We now have another, more specific and more helpful close reason that fits such questions:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

If the question is asking whether or not (yes/no) there is a *native* color picker control built into Windows Forms — as can be gleaned by the fact that the accepted answer mentions one — it should be edited to that effect so then the question doesn't become simply a "recommend your favorite third-party color-picker control" question.

Comment: [Yes/no questions don't really make good SO questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/186381) I wouldn't really want to be suggesting that the OP turn this question into a yes/no question.  It doesn't improve it; if anything it just makes it worse.